# Energy conservation in a ballistic pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, momentum

So I was thinking about this really simple situation and then I came across a little question. The situation is as follows:

There is a block of wood suspended from a ceiling like support with four strings. The strings are perfectly rigid and light with no friction between various parts of the string. I am imposing various other idealistic conditions as well like the absence of any dissipative forces, absence of any kind of internal friction or any strain in the solid block of wood.

Now with everything set up, if I project an ideal projectile into the wood from below, this projectile hits the block and gets embedded inside the block. This causes the block to rise and then fall. Now when the block has fallen the same distance it had raised it has the same kinetic energy as when it was hit by the projectile but now it is going down but the forces by the four string decreases it's kinetic energy to zero. Now since the strings did not not elongate the question I have is

Where did the kinetic energy go? It can't just disappear in thin air.

My natural answer was that the atoms in the block and the strings are all vibrating more than they did before so all the kinetic energy is still there but I was thinking if there is some other way of explaining where the energy went purely staying in classical Newtonian mechanics and not considering atomic motion because this situation and all the conditions are very classical and hence this situ must be explainable in a purely classical framework,

so is there way to explain this situation without considering atoms and staying purely in Newtonian mechanics?

Comment: What makes this situation different from any other [inelastic collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision)?

Comment: can you explain a bit more?